# Incrementing a number displayed and passing the number in the label to mysql database via php

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, label, increment

This is my html code to display a number in the html label

```
<tr>
    <td height="40" colspan="2" align=right>
        <div class="headbox" >Order No.</div>
    </td>
    <td align=left> 
        <div class="headbox">
            <label id=no></label>
        </div> <br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This are the 2 javascript functions that i am using to create the number and display on the label when the form is loaded!

```
function noDisplay(){
    var j=1;
    number=j+1;        
    document.getElementById("no").innerHTML=number;
}      
window.onload = function(){
    noDisplay()
};
```

Always the form is loaded the same number(i.e 1) is displayed i want to increment this by 1 and the displayed number needs to be passed to mysql database via php(i don't know how to pass the value displayed in a label into a php variable using post method

[image]

Here always the order number is 1 when the form is loaded i want to increment that value by 1 each time the form loads and pass that to mysql databse when the form is submitted please help me!

Comment: Give proper explanation about your problem

Comment: Are You using PHP as backend?

Comment: yep php is in the backend

Answer (score 0):

If You are using PHP as backend for Your form, then You juat need to pass last inserted id and increment it due to not overwrite another record.
Then, You will be available to use it dynamically.
Also, You can pass that number or get it with XHR Request (via AJAX call) and c hange it after call will be done.

**Update**

You should have next piece of PHP code (ex. last_order_id.php):

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type:application/json');
   $lastInsertedId = mysqli_query('select id from orders order by id desc limit 1');
   return json_encode(['status' => 1, 'data' => [ 'last_order_id' => $lastInsertedId + 1 ]]);
```

In AJAX call (You should provide at least jQuery v1.7) You should do like this when document is ready and when clicking on button:

```
$(document).ready(getLastId());

$('form').on('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Send data then call script
    getLastId();
})

function getLastId(){
      $.get('/last_order_id.php', function (response){
        $('label#no').text(response.data.last_order_id);
      });
}
```

Comment: yeah um asking how to do that?

Comment: You want to do it with ajax? It will be better

Comment: can i do with javascript only?

Comment: You should learn jQuery and for now standards You need to know it. I will give You example of code when will be available from laptop

Comment: great send me that :)

Comment: if You want me to help You build mini application - i can help You with that. Write me romanko95.rk@gmail.com